Android ROOM database query send null argument
I want to retrieve a List when user click on a Button
User specify which button by sending an Int and get the List
I wrote the following Query for it
@Query("SELECT image FROM BuildList_table WHERE classNumber = :classNumber ")
    suspend fun getListWithClassNumber(classNumber: Int): List<ItemData>

It's using this table :
@Entity(tableName = "BuildList_table")
data class BuildEntity(
    val listName: String,
    val classNumber:Int,
    var image: List<ItemData>,
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    val id: Int = 0
)

data class ItemData (
    var text: String ?= "akm",
    var image: Int ?= R.drawable.akm_sideview ,
    var type : Int ?= 0
)

Im calling it with
Button(onClick = {
            coroutineScope.launch {
                Toast.makeText(local, dao.getListWithClassNumber(1).toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }) {
            
        }

When the table is empty it send me [] which is fine but when the table is not empty it just send me : [ItemData(text=null, image = 0, type=null)] so every argument is null
I did a query using the appInspection tool :
SELECT image FROM BuildList_table WHERE classNumber = 1
And I get the right List fill with the good argument
I also tried calling the query directly from the DAO and not using my viewmodel and it doesn't change anything

Does it help to add “LIMIT 1” to the query?

Are you storing the image as json in the db? If yes, then are you using TypeConverter to convert to/from string to/from list

Yes Im using a TypeConverter for my list and using “LIMIT 1" does not affect the result
